# First query string parameter not parsed

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

My query must extract a query string parameter from a URL in a data column. Unfortunately, Kusto appears bugged in that the base URL is considered part of the first parameter's name as indicated in this example:

```
datatable (MyUrl:string)
[
"http://foo/?p1=bar&p2=baz",
"http://foo/?p1=bar&p2=quuz",
"http://roo/?p1=biz&p2=fizz"
]
| project parse_urlquery(MyUrl)["Query Parameters"]["http://foo/?p1"], parse_urlquery(MyUrl)["Query Parameters"]["p1"], parse_urlquery(MyUrl)["Query Parameters"]["p2"]
```

[image: Kusto output]

How can I reliably extract p1 (Note, it's not necessarily first in the actual URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you perhaps intend to use `parse_url()` and not `parse_urlquery()`?

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseurlfunction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseurlqueryfunction

```
datatable (MyUrl:string)
[
"http://foo/?p1=bar&p2=baz",
"http://foo/?p1=bar&p2=quuz",
"http://roo/?p1=biz&p2=fizz"
]
| project parse_url(MyUrl)["Query Parameters"]
```

```
Query Parameters
----------------
{
  "p1": "bar",
  "p2": "baz"
}
----------------
{
  "p1": "bar",
  "p2": "quuz"
}
----------------
{
  "p1": "biz",
  "p2": "fizz"
}
```

Comment: Indeed :-) Thank you for the quick reply.